# Replacing XML tag values

Tags: perl

This function replaces some XML tag values. The tags appear in the XML exactly once.I want to know if this can be done in a better way.

```
sub editConnConfig{
my ($DOMAIN,$rscDir,$walletDir,$DEFAULTPORT)=@_;
`perl -pi -e 's!<trustStore>.*?</trustStore>!<trustStore>$walletDir/fctrust.jks</trustStore>!sg' "$rscDir/ConnectionConfig.xml" 2>&1`;
`perl -pi -e 's!<keyStore>.*?</keyStore>!<keyStore>$walletDir/fckey.jks</keyStore>!sg' "$rscDir/ConnectionConfig.xml"`;
`perl -pi -e 's!<keyStorePassword>.*?</keyStorePassword>!<keyStorePassword>jkspass1</keyStorePassword>!sg' "$rscDir/ConnectionConfig.xml"`;
`perl -pi -e 's!<directoryName>.*?</directoryName>!<directoryName>$DOMAIN</directoryName>!sg' "$rscDir/ConnectionConfig.xml"`;
`perl -pi -e 's!<dbDaemonPort>.*?</dbDaemonPort>!<dbDaemonPort>$DEFAULTPORT</dbDaemonPort>!sg' "$rscDir/ConnectionConfig.xml"`;
}
```

Comment: Parsing XML using regular expressions is generally a bad idea, as it's not a regular language

Comment: If this is stuff that only you use (i.e. not deployed to servers or to customers), consider using [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib) and read http://stackoverflow.com/a/2980715/1331451. In fact, local::lib has already been pointed out to you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250162/read-ini-file-to-initialize-variables#comment56255095_34250162). ;)

Answer (score 7):

First and foremost, XML is not a regular language, and therefore parsing it using regular expressions is not appropriate, and is [asking for trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/641955).

Secondly, invoking `perl` within `perl` is clearly an awful idea. Invoking it multiple times is even worse.

As all the `s!!!` operations are performed on the same file, you could perform all of them at once in the same process, by separating them with semicolons, that is:

```
perl -pi -e 's!pattern1!replacement1!sg; s!pattern2!replacement2!sg' file
```

But as I said earlier, you should not call `perl` from within a `perl` function in a backtick expansion, but implement properly the operations (open file, read buffer, perform replacements, overwrite the file).

And instead of doing this using regular expressions, consider using an XML parser.

Comment: For some reason my organisation does not want us to use downloaded modules, I will re-write the function to open the file and make changes.

Comment: @MohimaChaudhuri, you may not have to install modules, you may copy the code of some existing tiny modules and use them in your code.